# Decode JSON String in Java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

How can I decode this JSON String which has been received as a parameter via the ajax call. This String is basically a Javascript Array which has been passed using `JSON.stringify`.

The format received at my Java End is something like this.

```
%5B%22Name%22%2C%22Vivek%22%2C%
```

how can i decode this String so that I can create a JSONArray from it using

```
JSONArray.fromObject
```

because passing the above mentioned format throws an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it is URL encoded. Try decoding it before parsing.

```
String decodedString = java.net.URLDecoder.decode("%5B%22Name%22%2C%22Vivek%22%2C%", "UTF-8");
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(decodedString);
```